# Effect of reloading assembly programatically in appdomain

Tags: c#, system.reflection

Suppose I have asp.net web application where particular assembly and types in it are already loaded in appdomain. If same assembly is programmatically loaded again using Assembly.Load() method from System.Reflection namespace then what will be side effects of it on application's

1. Performance
2. Memory consumption

Comment: Why would you load already loaded assembly? Just wondering!!

Comment: Loading an (_any_) assembly into an `AppDomain` will consume memory, and the `Assembly.Load` operation takes time - I don't think this is the answer you're looking for though - can you describe what problem you're trying to solve and what you think might be a challenge?

Comment: @vendettamit: We have existing application where few assemblies are reloaded with no reason and we are cleaning up code.

Comment: @PankajKapare just remove reloading of the Assemblies it is having effect  on Performance as well  as on Memory

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: My question was more from performance and memory consumption viewpoint. If type(s) is/are already loaded then does reloading overwrite already loaded types or loads in separate memory?

Comment: @PankajKapare From a .NET point of view, each `AppDomain` can be viewed as a separate 'process'. You can't _reload_ an assembly, you can only dump an entire `AppDomain` (and its loaded assemblies) and create a new one - there's no overwriting.